# почему слушатель событий не убирается?

Tags: javascript, listener

написал функцию для слежение следующего клика, если клик падает не туда, то тогда убирается стиль актиновности и слушатель событий стирается, но почему то слушатель остается

```
function selectToggle(e) {
        let selectWrapper = e.target.closest('.select')
        let selectOptionWrapper = selectWrapper.querySelector('div')
        console.log( e.target,selectOptionWrapper)

        if(!selectOptionWrapper){
            return
        }

        selectOptionWrapper.classList.toggle('select-option-wrapper--active')

        document.addEventListener('click', selectRemover.bind(this))

        function selectRemover(e){
            if(!e.target.closest('.select')){
                console.log('removeEventListner')
                selectOptionWrapper.classList.remove('select-option-wrapper--active')
                document.removeEventListener('click', selectRemover)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: добавьте перед if(!e.ta.....       console.log('call removeEventListner') И проследите что он появлялся

Comment: @AzizUmarov сейчас разобрался, проблема была в том что убрал bind(this) и тогда листнер отработает как нужно и удаляется

Answer (score 0):

Давайте разберёмся.
anyFunction.bind(context);

Создаст новую функцию с новым контекстом.

Пример

```js
function test(event){
 console.log(this===window);
}

let test1 = test.bind(button1);

console.log(test === test1);

document.addEventListener("click", test.bind(button1));
document.removeEventListener("click", test);
```

```html
<button id="button1" onclick="test()">test</button>
<button id="button2" onclick="test1()">test1</button>
```